# On an exercise concerning continuous random variables

Tags: probability

I'd like to understand how to deal with continuous random variables. Well, my problems concern the relationships between probability density function and the distribution function. I obtain the distribution function [resp. the probability density function] by integrating [resp. by deriving] the probability density function [resp. the distribution function]. But if I slightly change the random variable, how to compute both the distribution function and the probability density function? Below, I found a very interesting exercise on the subject. Can you help me to solve it, in order to better understand continuous random variables?

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)=3x^2 1_{[0,1]}(x)$.

1. Compute the distribution function of $X$.

My solution: it seems that
$$
\int_0^1 f_X(x)dx=1
$$
Now, as I need to find a function, I think that the correct way to integrate is
$$
\int_0^t f_X(x)dx
$$
How to integrate when there is an indicator function?

2. Compute mean and variance of X.

I found how to do these computations!

3. Set $Y = 1-X$. Compute the distribution function $F_Y$ of $Y$, and hence the probability density function $f_Y(y)$.

I have no clue.

4. Compute mean and variance of Y.

Very similar to part $2)$.

Comment: You’ve already figured out in (1) that you need to integrate over $[0,1]$. On that interval, the indicator is just multiplying by one... so you ignore it. However the distribution *function* takes variable input, you’re just integrating over a constant interval. Check your definitions. As for the others, you can very simply look it up! “Mean and variance of continuous random variable”

Comment: @FShrike I edited my question. Well, the problem occurs in parts 1 and 3. Can you provide me a detailed answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$*A series of strong hints.*

When asked to compute the distribution function in $(1)$, they mean find: $$F_X=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)\d t$$Which is known as the cumulative distribution function. It models the probability that $X\le x$. Since $f_X=0$ *outside of* $[0,1]$, due to the indicator function, the above integral reduces to (for $x\ge0$): $$\int_0^{\min\{1,x\}}f_X(t)\d t$$Note that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\equiv1$ on the interval $[0,1]$, so you can "ignore" it in the latter integration. We need to take a minimum since, if $x\gt1$, the integral vanishes on the region $(1,x]$ (because of the indicator function...). What happens if $x\lt0$? Can you piece together a pretty piecewise evaluation for $F_X$? $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}?&x\gt1\\?&0\le x\le1\\?&x\lt0\end{cases}$$

In $(4)$, note that $Y\le y\iff1-X\le y\iff1-y\le X$, so have a think about how to resolve from here.

Further clarification on $(1)$: $$\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\d t=\begin{cases}\int_{-\infty}^0f_X(t)\d t+\int_0^xf_X(t)\d t&x\le1\\\int_{-\infty}^0f_X(t)\d t+\int_1^xf_X(t)\d t+\int_0^1f_X(t)\d t&x\gt1\end{cases}$$Have a think about which integrals are relevant.